# Почему размер excel отчета увеличивается после развертывания на сервере и как с этим бороться?

Tags: excel, ssrs

При экспорте отчета в excel из VisualStudio размер файла 2.4мб, а после публикации отчета на сервере и експорт в excel с сервера размер файла 3.3мб, с чем это связано и как этого избежать?

Comment: А почему вообще это проблема? Возможно у вас формат файла меняется?

Comment: Формат файла одинаков - xlsx. Проблема так как чем тяжелее отчет - тем дольше он загружается и притормаживает при роботе с ним. А по скольку дальше ожидается формирование отчетов посложнее - то и размер их будет больше, а после выгрузки с сервера еще больше((